# Wagtail full width admin

Tags: django, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I have the following `StructBlock`

```py
class ArticleSectionBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
    sections = blocks.ListBlock(
        blocks.StructBlock(
            [("header", blocks.CharBlock()), ("content", blocks.RichTextBlock())]
        )
    )
```

I am using the above block in my page model as follows:

```py
content = StreamField(
    [("article_sections", blocks.ArticleSectionBlock())], null=False, blank=False
)
content_panels = Page.content_panels + [StreamFieldPanel("content")]
```

In the wagtail admin, this field is very narrow and hard to use:

[image]

Is there a way to make it full width in the admin to provide more space to type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wagtail 2.7 (due to be released in November 2019) will include a redesign of StreamField to address this problem and others. In the meantime, installing the [wagtail-react-streamfield](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail-react-streamfield) package will provide the improved design.

Answer (score 0):

I have not personally done this but try customizing the editor interface using custom css as described in [this section of the official documentation.](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/hooks.html#editor-interface)